# Send when creating event in PHP facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to POST a new event with fb Graph API (not the php-sdk)
actually, everything works fine, except for the picture thing.
Here is what i do:

```
<?php
public function publish($url){
        $params = $this->getParameter();
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);        
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $returnValue = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $returnValue;
    }

public function getParameter() {

        $params["access_token"] = FbAuthentication::getInstance()->getToken();
        foreach ($this as $attr => $value) {
            if( $value != null)
                $params[ $attr ] = $value;
        }

   //this things  is actually done inside an inheriting class (the $picture attr is protected)
        if( $this->picture != null){
            $real = realpath($this->picture);
            if(!file_exists($this->picture))
                throw new Exception("File $this->picture not found");
            $params[basename($real)]="@$real";

        }
        return $params;

    }
?>
```

The $params array is ok (i think). Here's a var_dump():

```
array(6) {
  ["access_token"]=>
  string(79) "......"
  ["name"]=>
  string(17) "Name example"
  ["description"]=>
  string(16) "Desc example"
  ["start_time"]=>
  string(19) "2011-03-22T18:00:00"
  ["end_time"]=>
  string(19) "2011-03-22T20:00:00"
  ["logo.gif"]=>
  string(26) "@/home/alessandro/logo.gif"
}
```

If i don't set the "$picture" parameter everything works well, but if I do put the image
I recive this error:

```
{"error": 
           {"type":"OAuthException",
            "message":"(#324) Missing or invalid image file"}
}
```

Any idea of how to fix it?
Thanks

Edit: for some unknown reason this things works well with a pnj/jpeg file.
It doesn't with a gif pic...